# Inmobi ads Displayed issue on Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, inmobi

I want to set the Inmobi ads on the bottom of the screen.

In **XAML** i set the Horizontal and Vertical alignment in bottom. when i saw the design i saw the AdView in bottom of screen but when i deploy it By default it appear in Middle.

I'm confused am i did mistake anywhere either it always appear on that place.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ControlPanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,55" Grid.Row="3" Width="480"  >
                <Ad:IMAdView
                    x:Name="AdView1"
                    RefreshInterval="30"
                    AdSize="15"
                    AppId="fcc4c048-4686-42bc-a40c-b7fe8da70b40"
                    Height="110" Width="480"
                    AnimationType="SLIDE_IN_LEFT" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Margin="0,0,0,30" >
                    <Ad:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
                        <Ad:IMAdRequest 
                            LocationInquiryAllowed="False"/>
                    </Ad:IMAdView.IMAdRequest>
                </Ad:IMAdView>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: may be the problem can be in your RowDefinitions. check it

Answer (score 1):

Changing your *stackpanel*'s **HorizontalAlignment** property from "Center" to "**Right**" will work for you...